# Can I pass multiple values into a Setter in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, properties, resx

Hello all I'm trying to build a save settings and to not expose my methods I'm trying to hide as many methods as I can from the actual runtime and running them all from setters and getters for all my IO.

I need to be able to pass both the Uri of a file location and a Dictionary into a method in order to do the call. I would put the file location into the resx, but I have to be able to allow system admins to change the locations of the files. all i am loading is in key value pairs into an xml.

What is going to be the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a code sample of the class you are trying to create and the properties for which you want to create the setter?

Comment: You can't, but using a struct as a type allows you to pass those values on the stack instead of the heap, not so nice syntax but is like passing 2+ values.

Comment: `I'm trying to hide as many methods as I can from the actual runtime and running them all from setters and getters for all my IO.` Why?

Comment: Getters and setters are actually just another kind of method. It is a good idea to keep interfaces small and simple, but there is no evil in using methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Tuples (when using .Net Framework 4.0+).

```
class SettingsClass
{
    public Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>> TwoValuesProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use it by:

```
SettingsClass settings = new SettingsClass();

settings.TwoValuesProperty = new Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>("URI", new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Comment: Thats a good idea I have only seen Tuples used in 2D game programming before. I didn't think to use it this way. I had thought about just using `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` But I think your way looks better. would there be any performance difference?

Comment: Nope. Tuples are just an ordinary types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But you can instead create a collection class of your properties and set values of each one.